# Getting error: non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context when trying to construct a class inside a static method

Tags: java, static

When trying to construct a class inside this method I get the error: `non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context`

```
public static void insert(int key, int value, Node[] hashTable){
        Node newNode = new Node(value);
```

I can't understand what I am doing wrong here, how else am I supposed to construct an object in this method, is it simply not possible?

Comment: Which line of code produces this error?

Comment: I suspect that `Node` is inner class.

Comment: Yes Node is an inner class, is that the problem? Sorry I should have specified

Comment: Yes it is the problem. Inner classes only exist within the context of an outer instance, and there is no outer instance in a static method.